# Scanner using with while loop and switch statement

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm creating a simple console app in Java and I have a trouble. This is my code:

```
boolean isActive = true;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
try {
    int option = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (option) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Search By Registration number: " +
                    "\n------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Enter registration number!");
            String regNumber = scanner.nextLine();
            if (regNumber == incorrect) {
                continue; // return to case 1 and ask enter regnumber one more time
            } else {
                // do stuff
            }

            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Exit the search option: ");
            isActive = false;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Your selection was wrong. Try one more time!");
            break;

    }
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("Your selection was wrong. Try one more time!");
}
scanner.nextLine();
} while (isActive);
```

And I can't to return to case 1 if an error occured. So, if error occured, the user must get the message About entering the registration number one more time and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **equals()** when you check a regNumber

```
if (regNumber.equals(incorrect)) {
      System.out.println("Incorrect!");
      continue; 
} else {
      System.out.println("Correct!");
}
```

But even then, your program doesn't work properly, change **String regNumber = scanner.nextLine()** on this:

```
String regNumber = scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a loop around your input for the regNumber, in order to listen for input while it's not correct.

```
String regNumber = incorrect;
// String is a reference type, therefore equality with another String's value
// must be checked with the equals() method

while(regNumber.equals(incorrect)){

    if (regNumber.equals(correct)) {
        // Do something if input is correct
    }

}
```

This may be not the exact solution you wanted, but think of the same concept and apply it to your program. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767379/8666160) for more information about String comparison. Hope this helped!